# How can I upgrade TLS verion to 1.2 on MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, devops

I have the MySQL version 5.7.26 that is using the TLS versions TLSv1.1. I had seen this when I had executed the command `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tls_version';`. And I would like to upgrade to version TLSv1.2. Unfortunately I can't find a  good tutorial site guiding me step by step on how to make this change. Can someone help me out. Thank you

P.S. I am running the server on Mac OS Catalina.

Comment: only 1.1 is shown? Your mysql version should support tls 1.2, so maybe the ssl library is old.

Comment: Ok, and how can I change the SSL library?

Comment: you can try brew upgrade openssl

Comment: Thanks this truly solved my problem. Kudos @g_bor !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the openssl library on your system does not support tls 1.2 yet.

You can try

```
brew upgrade openssl
```